# Proving that the number of conjugacy classes of a finite group $G$ equals the number of $G$'s irreducible representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, characters, characteristic-classes

**Preamble:** I want to understand why the number of irreducible representations of a finite group equals the number of conjugacy classes of the group. The only direct proof I managed to find is in the book *Representation Theory, A First Course*, where the authors prove in the proposition 2.30 that *the number of irreducible representations of a group $G$ is equal to the number of conjugacy classes of the group $G$.* The authors then state that this is equivalent for the characters $\{\chi_V\}$ forming an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{C}_{\text{class}}(G)$
, where $\mathbb{C}_{\text{class}}(G)$ is the set of class functions $f:G\to \mathbb{C}$ such that $\forall h \in G:f(hgh^{-1}) = f(g)$ that is, the class functions are constant on conjugacy classes. The given proof is the following

> Suppose that $\alpha:G\to \mathbb{C}$ is a class function and $(\alpha,\chi_V) = 0$ for all irreducible representations $V$; we must show that $\alpha = 0$. Consider the endomorphism $\varphi_{\alpha, V} = \sum\alpha(g) \cdot g:V\to V$. By Schur's lemma $\varphi_{\alpha, V} = \lambda \mathrm{Id}$; and if $n = \mathrm{dim}(V)$, then $\lambda = \frac{1}{n}\mathrm{tr}(\varphi_{\alpha, V}) = \frac{1}{n}\sum\alpha(g)\chi_V(g) = \frac{|G|}{n}\overline{(\alpha, \chi_{V^*})} = 0$. Thus $\varphi_{\alpha, V} = 0$, or $\sum\alpha(g)\cdot g = 0$ on any representation $V$ of $G$; in particular this will be true for the regular representation $V = R$. But in $R$ the elements $\{g \in G\}$, thought of as elements of $\mathrm{End}(R)$, are linearly independent. For example, the elements $\{g(e)\}$ are all independent. Thus $\alpha(g) = 0$ for all $g$, as required.

**Problem:** The proof above is nice and concise; my only problem with it is that I don't understand how it shows that number of conjugacy classes of $G$ = number of irreducible representations of $G$. Since I've just began learning representation theory, I think that a more direct/elementary proof suits me better

**Alternative approach:** One old representation theory exam asked essentially the same question by letting $A$ be the set of all conjugacy classes of $G$ and $B$ the set of all irreducible complex representations of $G$. Then, we are given an orthogonality relation $\sum_{a \in A}\frac{|a|}{|G|}\overline{\chi_{f}(a)}\chi_g(a) = \begin{cases}1 & f \cong g\\0 & f \not\cong g\end{cases}$, where $f, g \in B$, and $a$ is a representative of a conjugacy class and $|a|$ is the number of elements in the class. Our task is then to show that for $a_1, a_2 \in A:\sum_{f \in B}\overline{\chi_f(a_1)}\chi_f(a_2) = \begin{cases}\frac{|G|}{|a_1|}&: a_1 = a_2\\0 &: a_1 \neq a_2\end{cases}$

**Main question:** A given hint in the problem is that we should define a linear map from $\mathbb{C}^A = \{f:A\to \mathbb{C}\}$ to $\mathbb{C}^B = \{f:B\to \mathbb{C}\}$. I defined the function $\alpha_f(\chi_g) = \overline{\chi_f}\chi_g, f, g \in B$ and showed that this map is linear. I also reasoned why the map is injective: $\alpha(g) \equiv 0$ on $G$ means that either $\overline{\chi_f} \equiv 0$ which is impossible as $f$ is an irreducible representation, or $\chi_g \equiv 0$, which I suppose is possible if $\chi_g$ is the zero scalar multiple of some other character. Currently, I'm stuck at showing that $\alpha$ is surjective. Namely, I don't know how to reverse-engineer that any irrep. function has a pre-image in $\mathbb{C}^A$.

Comment: Let $C(G)$ be the vector space of class functions on $G$. We can count the dimension of this vector space in two ways: firstly by taking indicator functions on each conjugacy class, we count $\dim C(G)$ as the number of conjugacy classes. Second, by taking the characters of irreducible representations, we count $\dim C(G)$ as the number of irreducible representations. Seeing the the first set is a basis is easy, the second more subtle. The whole point is trying to figure out why (A) the irreducible characters span, and (B) the irreducible characters are linearly independent.

Comment: Showing (A) the irreducible characters span is essentially what the first quoted section in your question is doing. The inner product on class functions is a key tool for (B), since if you can find a set of vectors which are orthogonal (or even orthonormal) under an inner product, then that set is certainly independent. If you believe both (A) and (B), then you are done. I should mention also that one *should not expect* there to be a map from conjugacy classes to irreps: these sets are in bijection, but not canonically.

Comment: @Joppy Ah, I see! I am apparently a bit rusty with my linear algebra, as I was exactly confused *why* we wanted to prove that $\alpha \equiv 0$ in the quoted proof. Do you happen to know why the sum over the characters at an element is equal to the order of the group divided by the order of the conjugacy class of the element?

Comment: As you say, there are several proofs of this fact, but the difficulty in understanding it arises partly from the fact that there is no natural bijection between the conjugacy classes of $G$ and its irreducible complex representations - they just happen to have the same cardinality.